# SMO Copy database or remove all non-system database objects

Tags: sql-server, c#, smo

I have c# SMO script which copy all database objects to existed empty database or to a new database.

But this approach has two problems

1. Existed database is not empty, manual intervention is needed.
2. New database will have different options like DB Owner, disk
   management etc.

Because I need to Clone existed database from one instance to another and I am able to copy only database objects right now, therefore my question is

1. it is possible to create a new database according to settings of
   existed one ?
2. it is possible to drop all objects, regardless on dependencies, from existed database ?

my script look like

```
Transfer transfer = new Transfer(databaseSource);
transfer.CopyAllObjects = true;
transfer.CopyAllUsers = true;
transfer.Options.WithDependencies = true;
transfer.DestinationServer = serverDestination.Name;
transfer.DestinationDatabase = databaseDestination.Name;
transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = true;
transfer.CopySchema = true;
transfer.CopyData = true;
transfer.Options.Permissions = true;
transfer.Options.ContinueScriptingOnError = true;
transfer.TransferData();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `SELECT * FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.name = '<target_db_name>';` to obtain the existing settings for the database prior to running the transfer.  Store the results in a `DataSet` so you can potentially use them later.

If the database does not exist, you'll get no rows returned.  If the database does exist, you could drop the existing database as the first step.

After you run the `TransferData()` method, you could apply the necessary configuration changes based on the items in the `DataSet`.  For instance the `recovery_model_desc` column contents could be used to set the recovery model by running this code:  `ALTER DATABASE <target_db_name> SET RECOVERY = 'xxx';`  where `xxx` is the value contained in the column.

Comment: thank you, now i create and set target database manually (only one time) and run a script with option `transfer.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;` or maybe another solution could be use with different option `transfer.CreateTargetDatabase = true;` but in this scenario the script does not work remotely so i didn't test it.